# Convert hourly data into daily data and maintain factor columns

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data frame with a datetime column that includes hourly data. I would like to group the data by site (loc column) and calculate daily values for the remaining columns.

#### Current Code

I've tried very basic code. For example:

```
dfDay <- aggregate(df, list(df$DateTime), FUN=mean)
```

But this returns NA for the factor columns and does not group by loc.

#### Subset of Data

```
structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1583427600, 1583427600, 
1583427600, 1583427600, 1583427600, 1583427600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), mAOD = c(73.4675, 73.6048, 73.7507, 
74.0078, 74.0731, 74.1994), groundLevel = c(73.536, 73.68, 73.809, 
74.018, 73.912, 74.729), rel_ground = c(-0.0685000000000002, 
-0.0752000000000095, -0.0583000000000027, -0.0101999999999975, 
0.161100000000005, -0.529600000000002), siteTemp = c(6.75, 6.1, 
6.91, 7.52, 7.23, 5.48), baroTemp = c(7.57, 7.57, 7.57, 7.57, 
7.57, 7.57), beaverEvent = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), levels = c("BB", "AB", "D"), class = "factor"), mere = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("chapel", "hatch", "coleCrose", 
"crose"), class = "factor"), loc = c("SSSI3", "SSSI2", "B6", 
"SSSI1", "B8", "B3"), spi = c(1.3363327, 1.3363327, 1.3363327, 
1.3363327, 1.3363327, 1.3363327), spigroup = c("Moderately Wet", 
"Moderately Wet", "Moderately Wet", "Moderately Wet", "Moderately Wet", 
"Moderately Wet"), damEvent = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), year = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it this way:

1. transforming datetime to date
2. aggregate by loc and date
3. compute mean for all the numeric columns

Check if the output is what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dfDay <- df %>% mutate(only_date = date(DateTime)) %>% group_by(loc, only_date) %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, mean, na.rm=T)
## A tibble: 6 × 8
## Groups:   loc [6]
#  loc   only_date   mAOD groundLevel rel_ground siteTemp baroTemp   spi
#  <chr> <date>     <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1 B3    2020-03-05  74.2        74.7    -0.530      5.48     7.57  1.34
#2 B6    2020-03-05  73.8        73.8    -0.0583     6.91     7.57  1.34
#3 B8    2020-03-05  74.1        73.9     0.161      7.23     7.57  1.34
#4 SSSI1 2020-03-05  74.0        74.0    -0.0102     7.52     7.57  1.34
#5 SSSI2 2020-03-05  73.6        73.7    -0.0752     6.1      7.57  1.34
#6 SSSI3 2020-03-05  73.5        73.5    -0.0685     6.75     7.57  1.34
```

if you want to keep the factor columns as well:

```
dfDay <- df %>% mutate(only_date = date(DateTime)) %>% group_by(loc, only_date) %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ mean(.x, na.rm=T)), across(where(is.factor), ~ first(.x)), .groups='keep')

dfDay
## A tibble: 6 × 12
## Groups:   loc, only_date [6]
#  loc   only_date   mAOD groundLevel rel_ground siteTemp baroTemp   spi beaverEvent mere  damEvent year 
#  <chr> <date>     <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <fct>       <fct> <fct>    <fct>
#1 B3    2020-03-05  74.2        74.7    -0.530      5.48     7.57  1.34 BB          hatch 1        1    
#2 B6    2020-03-05  73.8        73.8    -0.0583     6.91     7.57  1.34 BB          hatch 1        1    
#3 B8    2020-03-05  74.1        73.9     0.161      7.23     7.57  1.34 BB          hatch 1        1    
#4 SSSI1 2020-03-05  74.0        74.0    -0.0102     7.52     7.57  1.34 BB          hatch 1        1    
#5 SSSI2 2020-03-05  73.6        73.7    -0.0752     6.1      7.57  1.34 BB          hatch 1        1    
#6 SSSI3 2020-03-05  73.5        73.5    -0.0685     6.75     7.57  1.34 BB          hatch 1        1
```

Comment: Thankyou. I still want to retain the columns with factors is that possible?

Comment: yes, you can but what statistics do you want to compute from them? if for example you want first(): dfDay <- df %>% mutate(only_date = date(DateTime)) %>% group_by(loc, only_date) %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ mean(.x, na.rm=T)), across(where(is.factor), ~ first(.x)), .groups='keep')

Comment: I will update the answer - editing now :)

Answer (score 1):

You were close with `aggregate`, don't give up.

It's easy, just subset df for numeric columns using `sapply(df, is.numeric)`, and in the `list` you need to include all grouping factors, that's all. The `with(df, .)` takes care that you don't need to write `df$` all the time.

```
with(df, aggregate(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], list(date=DateTime, loc=loc, beaverEvent=beaverEvent), mean))
#                  date   loc beaverEvent    mAOD groundLevel rel_ground siteTemp baroTemp      spi
# 1 2020-03-05 17:00:00    B3          BB 74.1994      74.729    -0.5296     5.48     7.57 1.336333
# 2 2020-03-05 17:00:00    B6          BB 73.7507      73.809    -0.0583     6.91     7.57 1.336333
# 3 2020-03-05 17:00:00    B8          BB 74.0731      73.912     0.1611     7.23     7.57 1.336333
# 4 2020-03-05 17:00:00 SSSI1          BB 74.0078      74.018    -0.0102     7.52     7.57 1.336333
# 5 2020-03-05 17:00:00 SSSI2          BB 73.6048      73.680    -0.0752     6.10     7.57 1.336333
# 6 2020-03-05 17:00:00 SSSI3          BB 73.4675      73.536    -0.0685     6.75     7.57 1.336333
```